# Strange behaviour on Safari when trying to submit form using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, safari

I am using i frame based mechanism to submit my login from and it is working fine on each and every browser except Safari (5.1.7).
Here is the HTML form I am using to submit the information

```
<form:form action="${loginActionUrl}" method="post" commandName="loginForm" id="header-signin" target="loginFrame" name="header-signin">
  <input type="text"    name="j_username" id="header-signin_j_username"> 
  <input type="password" name="j_password" id="header-signin_j_password"> 
  <input type="button" class="btn1" value="Sign In" id="login" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" onclick="JavaScript:triggerSigin('header-signin');" />
</form:form>
```

Here are the script I am using to submit form using JQuery

```
document.getElementById('header-signin_j_password').onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {  
        triggerSigin(this.form.id);
   }
}

function triggerSigin(formID){
    if(validateSigninForm(formID)){
        $( "#"+formID).submit();
    }
}
```

Everything is simple and without any complex logic, I have tested it on all available browser and it was working fine, but on the Safari, it is behaving in a very strange manner

1. If I hit the enter button after entering the password, sign in process is working perfectly fine.
2. If I fill each and every field and click on the login button, Safari is opening up a new tab and form is getting submitted to server with `username` and `password` field as null.
   If I close the extra window and again click on the sign in button, everything is working fine till I sign out and again try to sign in to the system.

I am not sure why Safari is opening a new browser window and why the form data is being submitted as null,  this behavior is only happening for the first time and subsequent click on signing button is working perfectly fine till I close the browser and open it again. 
Can any one help me to understand this issue

### Final output

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="loginFrame" hidden="true"> </iframe>
<form id="header-signin" name="header-signin" action="https://localhost/customer_login" method="post" target="loginFrame">
<div class="field-container">
    <label for="username">User Name</label> 
    <input type="text" name="j_username" id="header-signin_j_username"> 
  </div>
  <div class="field-container">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="j_password" id="header-signin_j_password"> <a href="/login/pw/request/external" class="forgot">Forgot password?</a>
   </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn1" value="Sign In" id="login" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" onclick="JavaScript:return validateSigninForm();">
</form>
```

I am not sure

1. Why this is working in Safari when I am hitting enter button and why it is not working when clicking on the button.
2. This issue is for the first click, once I close the other window and again click on the login button, everything is working fine in Safari also.

Comment: FYI, you don't need `Javascript:` in `onclick` attributes. That's only used in attributes that contain a URL, such as `href`.

Comment: What is the generated code? Also, this is happening on Safari for Windows, right?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: I have updated the post with the final HTML output and yes I am using Safari for window

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but you have `signin_j_password` in JS, but `header-signin_j_password` in HTML.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Sorry that was a typo :(

Answer (score 1):

Use [button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) tag instead of input tag.

Also, add below line in CSS:

```
button {-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

Or keep using input tag and add below line:

```
input {-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

It should work fine.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working.issue above is occurring only for the first time on Safari

Comment: i found that this does not fix it for mobile safari. desktop safari works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't seem to be the cause. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zen963fo/ (I added my own `validateSigninForm()` to make the posted code work)

Can you share your `validateSigninForm()` function? Perhaps it's something in there.

I've also made a simplified version of your JS, http://jsfiddle.net/zen963fo/2/, which ***may*** resolve some of the issues you're experiencing just by streamlining the submission process.

Comment: i found that this does not fix it for mobile safari. desktop safari works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answer your query. If you enabled developer tools in safari, try disable it and then try again.

Please refer to this link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2754821?tstart=0